# Has anyone tried oracle export : EXPDP on the remote machine?

Tags: oracle, datapump, data-export, expdp

I am trying to export a dump file and log file on a remote machine using oracle expdp.
However i am getting the following error :

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g 
Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing 
options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

Command run on remote machine  host-name 'Local' using oracle client are :

```
SQL> create directory expdp_dir as '/vault2/expdp_dir';
SQL> grant read,write on directory expdp_dir to dbuser;
expdp dbuser/dbpwd@SID SCHEMAS=dbuser DIRECTORY=expdp_dir DUMPFILE=testDB24NOV17.dmp logfile=testDB24NOV17.log EXCLUDE=STATISTICS
```

Note vault 2 is mounted on a remote machine with hostname 'Local'. The database is on a machine with hostname TestDB.

The OS is RHEL6.

Any thoughts /ideas on making this operation successful would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one:
as per Oracle Doc.ID Doc ID 1305166.1

The errors can have multiple causes. Known causes are listed below.

1. One of the usual reasons for this problem to occur is when the listener process has not been started under the same account as the database instance service. The listener forks the new server process and when this runs under a different security context as the database, then access to directories and files are likely impacted.

Please verify the following information:
1) the output of:
ps -ef | grep SMON
2) the output of:
ps -ef | grep tnslsnr
3) the output of: 
ps -ef|grep LIST
4) the output of:
ls -ld

Note:
When using ASM, the listener may have been started from the ASM Home instead of the RDBMS Home. Depending on your security settings, this may give to this issue.

One more:
4. Directory path/folder exists but create directory is executed by a different user in the database and the import is run by a different user.

Solution:
1. Make sure the listener and instance services are started from the same account.

2. Make sure that the directory are shared between nodes so that the directory can be accessed on any instance, or, create a folder similar to the other nodes locally, if there is already a folder created locally on the all the node with the same file directory path structure check if the permission are correct.
3. Make sure the folder exist has specified in during creation in the "CREATE DIRECTORY" syntax command.
4. Grant the required permission to the importing user to use the directory.

grant read, write on directory  to ;

If above 4 possible causes and solutions are not applicable at your end, please check if the user has proper permission to export to run utl_file package.

Hope it helps.